# Cloning kendo DataSource removes CRUD?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I am trying to clone a Kendo DataSource into a new DataSource but it seems to be losing any of the options that were set on the old one. I might not be cloning/copying it in the right way though so any suggestions are appreciated.

Here is how I'm currently cloning:

```
var questionItemGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(viewModel.baSurveyQuestionItemTemplateDataSource);
questionItemGridDataSource.query({
    filter: {
        logic: "or",
        filters: [
            {
                field: "BaSurveyQuestionTemplateId",
                operator: "eq",
                value: questionId
            },
            {
                field: "Name",
                operator: "eq",
                value: ""
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

It copies it over and sets the filter just fine but if I do

```
alert(questionItemGridDataSource.options.transport.read.url)
```

it just alerts `undefined`.

**EDIT:**

I'm aware that I can just set it "manually" by putting

```
questionItemGridDataSource.options.transport = viewModel.baSurveyQuestionItemTemplateDataSource.options.transport;
```

afterward, but that just seems unnecessary and there surely is a way to clone a datasource without having to reset the CRUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are passing a DataSource instance instead of a settings object. Try

```
var questionItemGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource(viewModel.baSurveyQuestionItemTemplateDataSource.options);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I didn't think it would be this easy of a fix but it was. Thanks a ton!